# ModuleNotFoundError Even Though Module Shows Up On pip3 list

Tags: python, selenium, session, pip, selenium-chromedriver

I keep getting this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requestium'`

Even though when I do `pip3 list`, requestium is in there. What are some possible reasons? What can I do to fix this. I'm thinking that its most likely something to do with my files but I can't seem to nail it down.

The line of code where I get the error is,
`from requestium import Session`

Comment: Do you have python2 and python3 both installed in your machine?

Comment: @RanikaNisal I do have python 3 but not python 2? Do I need them both?

Comment: No, a common reason for missing imports is installing the requirement from one version and then importing it from another. Just checking whether that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate your virtual environment? because I can install and use it.

Maybe, you might miss one of the following steps:

- Activate your virtual environment: `workon vision`

  [image]

  Here my virtual environment name is `vision`
- Install your package: `pip3 install requestium`
- Finally use `requestium` to import `Session`

[image]

If you have done all the steps and still have an error, I suggest create a new environment and apply the three steps. Good luck